# I am getting this issue while using moti library with react native

Tags: react-native, moti

I installed reanimated and moti library both and added reanimated plugin in babe-config-js file still getting this issue

Comment: What issue do you have?

Comment: You did not include your issue, but if it causes an error in your app when you try to debug it, then it is related to the use of Turbomodul in Reanimated2. This means that you need to create a customs setup for debugging when using Reanimated or Moti